# Kubernetes - Does IP Address of Service Object change?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-deployment, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I want to make use of NetworkPolicy for Egress Traffic from one set of Pods to another set of Pods.
So, I want to allow egress traffic from pods with label foo:bar only to pods with label foo:beer

Currently all Pods with label are behind one Service Object of type ClusterIP.

So can I use the IP of Service Object for the Egress Network Policy? If that IP does not change frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the IP address of the Service object for the Egress Network Policy. As you mentioned, all Pods with the label are behind one Service Object of type ClusterIP, which means that the IP address of the Service object is stable as long as the Service object is not deleted and recreated.

To configure the Egress Network Policy to allow egress traffic from pods with label foo:bar only to pods with label foo:beer, you can use the following YAML configuration:

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: allow-foo-bar-to-foo-beer
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      foo: bar
  egress:
  - to:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          foo: beer
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

This Network Policy allows egress traffic from Pods with label foo:bar to Pods with label foo:beer, and blocks egress traffic to any other Pods. The to field specifies the destination Pods that the egress traffic is allowed to, and the podSelector matches the Pods with the label foo:beer. The policyTypes field specifies that this policy applies only to egress traffic.

You can apply this Network Policy to your cluster using the kubectl apply command `kubectl apply -f <filename>.yaml`